# Need help in installing anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried installing anaconda for my AI project using python. When I try to install anaconda on to my new laptop but when the prompt comes to where I should be saving my file I get this warning "Destination folder contains 1 space. This can cause problems with several conda packages. Please consider removing the space."

I am trying to save the file on my C drive but I keep getting this warning and my laptop is also new.
How do solve this issue.
Please help

Answer (score 3):

It might be because your username has space in it like `C:\Jon Doe\Anaconda3\`
Install anaconda at `C:\Anaconda3\` or something

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

There are two options which can fix your issue:

1. Run an installer as administrator
2. Create a new folder on your disk C in root without any spaces

Comment: Strongly recommend against admin install - this only complicates things and really only system administrators need to resort to this.